# Vote on tag synonyms

Tags: discussion

I suggested a couple tag synonyms more than a year ago and they have no approval votes yet. Other tag synonyms suggestions are waiting for approval since 2014.

I guess this is not because people don't agree with those tag synonyms but because nobody visit that page and they don't show up in the review queues.

So this is a call to visit

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=synonym

In SE Meta it looks that adding and review queue for tags synonyms have been proposed but not implemented. It would make sense.